# Data Types in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi guys so I am working around a datatype that is "int" and "double"... but how do I pass it in the text such that I can have a parenthesis or bracket around my int like this; (260) and a currency or letters attached to my double like this; $20.00 or GHS15.00
any help

this is my code;

```
class FoodDetails {
  final Color primaryColor, backColor;
  final double width, productRate, productPrice;
  final String productUrl, productName;

  FoodDetails({
    this.primaryColor,
    this.backColor,
    this.width,
    this.productRate,
    this.productUrl,
    this.productName,
    this.productPrice,
  });
}

List<FoodDetails> demoFoods = [
  FoodDetails(
    productName: 'Burger + Fries',
    productPrice: 20.00,
    productRate: 3.5,
    productUrl: 'assets/images/kfc1.png',
    backColor: Colors.orange.shade600,
  ),
  FoodDetails(
    productName: 'Peperoni Pizza',
    productPrice: 45.00,
    productRate: 3.5,
    productUrl: 'assets/images/pizza2.png',
    backColor: Colors.orangeAccent.shade100,
  ),
  FoodDetails(
    productName: 'Sundae IceCream',
    productPrice: 40.00,
    productRate: 5.0,
    productUrl: 'assets/images/regularsundae.png',
    backColor: Colors.purple,
  ),
  FoodDetails(
    productName: 'Chicken Nuggets 2pcs.',
    productPrice: 35.05,
    productRate: 3.6,
    productUrl: 'assets/images/kfc2.png',
    backColor: Colors.amber.shade50,
  ),
];
```

this is where I am passing the datatypes just read and follow;

```
    class FoodCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
      height: getProportionateScreenHeight(220),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: PageView.builder(
              onPageChanged: (value) {},
              controller: PageController(
                initialPage: 0,
              ),
              itemCount: demoFoods.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: demoFoods[index].backColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(demoFoods[index].productUrl),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      blurRadius: 4.0,
                      offset: Offset(3.0, 3.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 70,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(10),
                        vertical: getProportionateScreenHeight(5),
                      ),
                      decoration: cardInfoDecoration,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                demoFoods[index].productName,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: CupertinoColors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                decoration: likedWidgetDecoration,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.near_me,
                                  size: 17.0,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  demoFoods[index].productRate.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17.5,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: getProportionateScreenWidth(10)),
                                buildSmoothStarRating(index),
                                Spacer(),
                                Text(
                                  demoFoods[index].productPrice.toString(),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17.5,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
var myInt = 42;

Text('\$$myInt ') // $42
Text('\$($myInt) ') // $(42)
Text('GHS$myInt ') // GHS42
```

Comment: well that is what I am trying to achieve but not with this method.. I just updated my question  check my code

Comment: then do it like this `'\$(' + demoFoods[index].productPrice.toString() + ')'`

Comment: ok so this is with bracket and the currency, I got this $(200)
but how do I achieve it this way;  $200 or GHS200
and also how do I Achieve just this (200)

Comment: just remove the bracket on each side `'\$' + demoFoods[index].productPrice.toString()`

Comment: I guess  same applies with the getting only the Paranthesis

Comment: Consider marking this as the right answer if it helped you

Comment: sorry... I forgot